# Initializing Repo Object With Git Package in Python

Tags: python, api

I have been working for days on how to check if a file is in a specific directory, and I narrowed the question down the following: initialize a repo object with the git package in python?

I have looked elsewhere and have found the following code: `git.Repo.init(self.repo_path)`. But what is repo_path? How do you grab it? Alternatively, some people use `os.path.exists(filePathAndName)`, but this still does not help. How do you get the filePathAndName? And does this solution assume that your github is downloaded to your desktop?

In essence, the code on the internet seems to lack context, but I am sure I am missing something. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You start by saying you want "to check if a file is in a specific directory".  How did you get from there to git?

Answer (score 0):

`repo_path` is the name of the variable, whose value is the path to the repo/directory. You took this part out of its context, where `self.repo_path` is surely defined. The same goes for `filePathAndName`.
Using Git, based on the description of your problem, seems irrelevant. And it lead you to an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) : "how to initialize a git repo" instead of your actual problem "how to check if file exists".

You seem to lack programming knowledge, notably how variables work. Here is a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-variables/) about them.
In short, you can associate values to certain names. For example :

```py
filePathAndName = 'path/to/file.txt'  # storing the value inside the variable
os.path.exists(filePathAndName)  # using the variable as parameter to a function call
```

which is basically the same as :

```py
os.path.exists('path/to/file.txt')  # using the value directly for the function
```

and is a correct way to get your answer.

If you meant to check if a certain file exists in a Git repository, it is a bit more difficult because the file could exist in a different [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control)), currently not existing on your filesystem. So a Git library may be of use there to get this info.
Here is an example based on the [GitPython's tutorial](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type) :

```
# having installed the library "GitPython" beforehand
from git import Repo
path_to_my_file = 'path/to/repo/somewhere/inside/there/is/file.txt'
path_to_my_repo = 'path/to/repo'
my_repo = Repo(path_to_my_repo)
# iterate over the repo's branches to check if they contain your file
```

I hope this clarifies the subject we are talking about.